# What's the difference between "belong TO me" and "belong WITH me"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

What's the difference between "belong **to** me" and "belong **with** me"?

For example:

> "My darling, I'm very happy that you belong **to** me."
>
> "My darling, I'm very happy that you belong **with** me." (one example [in a song](https://youtu.be/sG4HXBuzXtk?t=45))

What's the difference between these two sentences?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> *You belong **to** me*
>    I "own" you - I have "rights" over you, I can make decisions on your behalf, etc.
>    Often with the implication that ***I*** define the "value judgement" framework governing our relationship.
>
> *You belong **with** me*
>    It is right and proper that you should be close to me
>    Often with the implication that the *reason* for this assertion is either to comply with some "external" value system, or because it's in your best interests (not necessarily just because it's what ***I*** want).

As an example of a clear-cut differentiating context, suppose on his first day at a new school, a student is unsure whether to go into classroom A or classroom B. A second student - himself a new arrival - knows that *all* new students should report to classroom A on their first day. He might say *You belong with me*, as he invites the other to follow him into the correct classroom.

That second student would never say *You belong **to** me*. But if it was the *teacher* (about to go into classroom A herself, and having been asked by the first new arrival where he should go), it would be at least *feasible*<sup>1</sup> for her to use ***to*** instead of ***with***.

---

<sup>1</sup> As per comments below, at least *some* people would find the teacher's use of *belong **to*** inappropriate / offensive. Which simply goes to prove the point that asserting a *person* "belongs to" another person strongly implies that the (usually, metaphoric) "owner" may be exercising undue dominance.

Comment: it would be inappropriate for the teacher to use to

Comment: @WendyG: I did only say *feasible*, but honestly, I think saying it would be "inappropriate" is a bit over-sensitive. Would you excuse the teacher if she said *You belong **to my class**?* (Yeah, yeah - I know that in practice she'd be more likely to say *You belong **in** my class*, but that's not the point.)

Comment: inappropriate may have been the wrong word in a meToo world. I was meaning unsuitable, it turns out according to cambridge this is only an american usage, you learn something every day

Comment: Overall, +1 but I agree with Wendy here.

Comment: @WendyG: "only an american usage"? But I'm unmistakably *British*, and I have no problem with it. As regards Cambridge Dictionary, I think that (1) - you're misinterpreting what they say - which is just about the specific word ***belong***, not the significance of the preposition ***to***. (2) Cambridge are either just plain *wrong* in what they're trying to say, or (3) it's a kind of "page formatting error" that they happen to have a section heading *"belong" in American English* (but no *British English* section, despite it being essentially a British-based publication).

Comment: It is not offensive. It just wouldn't be said like that by a teacher. Come on. "You belong to my class" is not " You belong to me", that sounds like a boyfriend or girlfriend, even if you are in the middle of the pond on a boat.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry I was meaning the cambridge dictionary says that inappropriate meaning unsuitable is an american english meaning

Comment: @WendyG: oic. Well, noting that Cambridge only have section headers *"inappropriate" in American English* and *"inappropriate" in Business English*, I think it's just an artifact of how those pages are (semi-automatically?) laid out, perhaps somehow linked to various corpuses within which the particular citations might have been found. Again, I think they're (deliberately or accidentally) posting misleading stuff, impliying UK/US usage splits that don't in fact exist.

Comment: The more authoritarian a school environment, the more likely it would be to hear a teacher or administrator use "you belong to me", as in, "When you are in my class, you belong to me. You will do what I say, when I say, and how I say to do it..."  But I think that usage just reinforces the ownership aspect of the phrase in the sense that the teacher "owns" hiser class and the students in the class are subject to that ownership.  Or think of the military drill sergeant, "For the next 16 weeks, maggot, you belong to me!"

Comment: @WendyG "inappropriate" can have either definition, but when talking about how a student is treated by a teacher it most often has an extremely particular connotation. I've had plenty of teachers say "you belong to me" in certain situations (e.g. "for the next five minutes you belong to me, and I will not allow you to leave class early"). It seems a little strange in the given situation (with a teacher shepherding a lost student to the right classroom), but I can see it sounding natural given the right teacher.

Comment: @Lambie I've had a teacher say exactly that to me. "Is this the right class?" "Yep, you belong to **me** this quarter *laughs*". I've also gotten similar ones to what DarthFennec described. "Belong to me" has been an oddly common phrase from teachers in my life, now that I think about it.

Comment: @Aethenosity The teacher laughed precisely because of saying: belong ***to*** me. A teacher normally would not say that. That is why it is funny. Otherwise, there would be no point in saying it. I just know the difference between **belong to someone** and ***belong in a place***. "Yep, you belong to me this quarter (laughs)" is the only reasonable interpretation of how ***you wrote it***. These expressions are not exactly teacher-speak at all.

Comment: @Lambie I also know the difference. You are making a black and white statement, and I am providing you evidence that there is more grey than you think. That may be the only 'reasonable' interpretation TO YOU, but it isn't to me. Let's agree to disagree, I just wanted to provide my perspective, and you seem more interested in proving that you are "right" and I am "wrong" despite my broad experience with it (remember, 20-30 different teachers have said this).

Comment: @Aethenosity: Your point is both highly relevant and well set out. It's often misleading to make *definitive* assertions about what usages are "valid / credible", or "completely unacceptable". In retrospect perhaps I should have tried harder to come up with a "contrasting" example where the ***belong to*** version would be more generally accepted. But at the time I felt justified in saying the one I went with was a "clear-cut differentiating context" mainly because the *first* half of the pair (that the second student would *never* use the ***with*** construction there) was beyond contention.

Answer (score 9):

“Belong **to** me” suggests possession. When something belongs to you, you own it. But when speaking about people the possession is of course not literal.

“Belong **with** me” does not have the connotation of possession- it is just saying the person or thing and the speaker (“me”) should be together.

When talking about romantic partners, I think the former (“to”) suggests an existing relationship (“you are already my partner and I am happy about that”), whereas the latter (“with”) suggests a desire that the subject be in a relationship with the speaker (“you should be my partner”/“I wish you were my partner”).

Answer (score 5):

> You belong **to** me I "own" you
>
> - I have "rights" over you, I can make decisions on your behalf, etc.
>     Often with the implication that I
>     define the "value judgement" framework governing our relationship.
>
> You belong **with** me
>
> - It is right and proper that you should be close to me.
>     Often with the implication that the reason for this assertion is
>     either to comply with some "external" value system, or because it's in
>     your best interests (not necessarily just because it's what I want).

I have stolen this section completely from Fumble Fingers answer, as I agree with this totally. But I disagree with the analysis there.

Many people still romantically love the idea of "belonging to" someone, see this Dean Martin song:

> You Belong to Me
>
> Dean Martin
>
> Watch the sunrise on a tropic isle
>   See the pyramids along the Nile
>   Just remember darlin', all the while
>   You belong to me

BUT

Many people dislike the phrase, as they don't like being described as being owned by someone.  This takes in the background of women literally being their husbands property for hundreds of years in the UK*.

To contrast here is the Police Song "Every Breath You Take", some people consider this a romantic song even though it was written to be a creepy song about a stalker [citation of Sting](https://www.smoothradio.com/features/every-breath-you-take-police-lyrics-meaning/)

> Every single day
>   Every word you say
>   Every game you play
>   Every night you stay
>   I'll be watching you
>
> Oh can't you see
>   You belong to me
>   My
>   poor heart aches
>   With every step you take

And it takes in the
controlling nature of some relationships where one partner has the belief they are correct to control completely the other partner's every action and sometimes thoughts.

Even if people don't think of literal ownership, it sounds possessive and slightly controlling.

I would imagine the descendants of slaves are also not keen on this terminology, but I base this on nothing more than how I think I would feel.

So I would recommend not using the TO form yourself, as you never know how the other person will take it.

---

*I believe America is the same but my American social history is not good enough to make a definite statement.

Comment: Contrast those lyrics with the lyrics to Sting's Every Breath You Take in which "You belong to me" distinctly adds to the creepiness of  all the "I'll be watching you" verses.  The choruses and the bridge seem to lean more toward to the romantic interpretation taking "to" to mean "with". But I think Sting very deliberately chose to use "You belong to me" instead of "with me" to end the first line of the chorus; to keep the creepiness simmering, and to twist the straight-up lonely romantic achiness of the bridge more toward creepy-land.

Comment: _"Many people are **beginning** to dislike the phrase"_ : Beginning to? using the phrase "you belong to me" in this sort of relationship context has always had an uncomfortable edge to it & been subject to disapproval throughout my life, not counting early childhood that's from the 70's on, so you have that wrong.

Comment: @geneSummons in interviews Sting is confused why people find that song as romantic it was written as a creepy stalker song.

Comment: @Pelinore, That is me couching my lack of history on the issue in vague phrases.  And if I wanted a pedantic (hopefully humorous response) I could say dislike since the 60s is recently as women have belonged to men for hundreds of years